# Regular Expression for website

Tags: python, regex, spyder

http://www.bbc.com/news/business-41097280

Is the website I want the regular expression for.

So far, I am using the following, where

```
'.+\/news\/business[-.]\d{8}$
```

Which is part of this code segment here, used with Scrapy

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class TryItem(Item):
    url = Field()

class BbchrcrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "bbchrcrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["www.bbc.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.bbc.com/news/business-']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['.+\/news\/business+\-d{8}$']), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        Item = TryItem()
        Item['url'] = response.url
        yield Item
```

What's the correct way to get the URL there for extracting multiple pages with the same format?

The result should collect URLs with the following format:

bbc.com/news/business-########

Comment: `.+/news/business-\d{8}` should be enough.

Comment: You used  a different code. Your `\-d{8}` in the code matches `-` and 8 `d`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
pattern = "bbc\.com/news/business-\d+"
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[pattern]), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)
```